# Why MDDialog height do not changing in kivymd?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I have implemented simple MDDialog in kivymd. But height is not changing. How can I change height of dialog box?

I have created a boxlayout then added four labels to them. Then I have added it to dialog box. It works but height is not changing.

**main.py**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivy.metrics import dp
from build_string import helper_string
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass


class MainApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.dialog = ""

        self.sm = Builder.load_string(helper_string)
        return self.sm

    def show_alert_dialog(self):
        if not self.dialog:
            self.dialog = MDDialog(
                size_hint= [0.9, None],
                type="custom",
                height=dp(800)
            )

            box = MDBoxLayout(
                orientation='vertical',
                adaptive_height=True,
                padding=dp(28),
                spacing=dp(15))

            l1 = MDLabel(text="Label 1")
            box.add_widget(l1)

            l2 = MDLabel(text="Label 2")
            box.add_widget(l2)

            l3 = MDLabel(text="Label 3")
            box.add_widget(l3)

            l4 = MDLabel(text="Label 4")
            box.add_widget(l4)

            self.dialog.add_widget(box)

        self.dialog.open()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

**build_string.py**

```
helper_string = """
ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager
    MainScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: 'main_screen'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        spacing: "5dp"

        MDToolbar:
            id: toolbar
            pos_hint: {'bottom': 1}
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: app.show_alert_dialog()]]   
"""
```

How can I change the height of the MDDialog?

What will be alternative to show this as popup message with custom height?

Comment: It looks like it's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

In MDDialog, it only changes height when the type='custom' and only if contetnt_cls parameter is available. So when adding content to the MDDialog, instead of adding directly into the dialog use another class with your content and add it with **content_cls** argument.
Now change the height of the content class and then MDDialog will set the dialog height according to the height of content_cls with update_height method.

For example this is how it do.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel

helper_string = """
ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager
    MainScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: 'main_screen'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        spacing: "5dp"
        MDToolbar:
            id: toolbar
            pos_hint: {'bottom': 1}
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: app.show_alert_dialog()]]   
"""


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass


dialog_contetnt = Builder.load_string("""
<DialogContent>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint_y: None
    height: dp(200)
    MDLabel:
        text: 'Label 1'
    MDLabel:
        text: 'Label 2'
    MDLabel:
        text: 'Label 3'
    MDLabel:
        text: 'Label 4'
        
""")

class DialogContent(MDBoxLayout):
    pass


class MainApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.dialog = ""

        self.sm = Builder.load_string(helper_string)
        return self.sm

    def show_alert_dialog(self):
        if not self.dialog:
            self.dialog = MDDialog(
                size_hint= [0.9, None],
                type="custom",
                content_cls=DialogContent(),
            )

        self.dialog.open()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```